# Load JSON file to couchbase server

Tags: json, couchbase, nosql

I have JSON file with 1.5GB size and i need to upload this to a couchbase server bucket. I use the following command to load.

```
cbdocloader -n 10.5.2.117:8091 -u Administrator -p password -b mybucket ../samples/gamesim.zip
```

Unfortunately, it beaks because of memory issue. Can someone suggest a better method or an optimal way to solve this ? My machine is having 15GB memory and Intel Xeon CPU with 2.50GHz speed.

Thanks in advance,
Tismon Varghese.

Comment: so you've provided a different zip than the example? and your 1.5GB of JSON is actually made of several documents right?

Comment: Yes, the .zip is different from example and is just a simple json array (of users login details- username, ip, loginTime, logInFrom) etc

Comment: IIRC the content of the zip is supposed to be individual.json files, one for each document in the dB... Couchbase can only store single documents of up to 20MB (and less is recommended) so that maybe the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  used a small java program to implement this. You can refer this link `http://architects.dzone.com/articles/sql-nosql-copy-your-data-mysql`
Migrated one of the large single MySQL databse table(28Lac records) using this(you can migrate entire database using this program, even all databases ).

MySQL OS : Ubuntu 14.04 (Amazon Instance)
Memory   : 7.4G

Couchbase OS : Ubuntu 14.04 (Amazon Instance)
Memory       : 15G  (2xlarge instance)
Java         : java version "1.7.0_79"
`Note: Memory eaten up while using a Amazone machine with Memory 7.4G`

Step 1. Download `couchbase-sql-importer` from `github` (https://github.com/tgrall/couchbase-sql-importer) to Couchase server, some where in your home folder and extract it.

Step3. Download 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar' from http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/ to the 'couchbase-sql-importer-master' (extrated folder). While dowloding jar file from mysql site, you need to select the jar fie version from drop down.

Step4.Download 'CouchbaseSqlImporter.jar' from https://www.dropbox.com/s/pcnwukw2j8xe2d2/CouchbaseSqlImporter.jar to the folder 'couchbase-sql-importer-master'.

Step5.Edit the fie 'import.properties' like,

```
## SQL Information ##
sql.connection=jdbc:mysql://mysql_server_ip:3306/database_name
sql.username=mysql_user_name
sql.password=myql_password

## Couchbase Information ##
cb.uris=http://localhost:8091/pools
cb.bucket=bucket_name
cb.password=bucket's_password

## Import information
import.tables=specific_table_name
import.createViews=true
import.typefield=
import.fieldcase=none
```

Save this file.

### Important things to notice

```
cb.password=bucket's_password     
// you can set passwords for each bucket via Couchbase console. Select bucket and edit the feild 'Access Control' and give password in there and save.



import.tables=All  //For migrating entire table.

If import.properties file not found in 'couchbase-sql-importer-master' folder, then search and find sample import.properties file and rename it to so.
```

Step6. Run this command in terminal,

```
java -cp "./CouchbaseSqlImporter.jar:./mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar" com.couchbase.util.SqlImporter import.properties
```

Output

---

```
############################################
#         COUCHBASE SQL IMPORTER           #
############################################



Importing table(s)
    from :  jdbc:mysql://XXXX:3306/XXX
    to :    [http://localhost:8091/pools] - XXXX

  Exporting Table : XXXX


 Create Couchbase views for XXXX
    2801937 records moved to Couchbase.


 Create Couchbase views for 'types' ....


              FINISHED
############################################

Check Couchbase console for verifying  the content.
```

Hope this is crystal clear for you :) 
Thanks.